# ArcGIS Feature layer data update using API in PHP

Tags: php, arcgis-js-api

I'm facing an issue with update data on the ArcGIS feature layer using API in PHP. Data is updating on the feature layer as expected, But data on the map is not representing. Every time when I'm pushing data to the Feature layer, Map is showing blank. But it's data section showing correct data.

Below is my code sample:-

```
<?php

$feature = [
    'geometry' => [
        'longitude' => $longitude,
        'latitude' => $latitude
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'id'                                => (int) $item->id,
        'project_name'                      => (string) $item->project_name,
        'queue_position'                    => (string) $item->queue_position,
        'request_receive_date'              => $item->request_receive_date,
        'queue_date'                        => $item->queue_date,
        'application_status'                => (string) $item->application_status,
        'study_process'                     => (string) $item->study_process,
        'type_1'                            => (string) $item->type_1,
        'type_2'                            => (string) $item->type_2,
        'fuel_1'                            => (string) $item->fuel_1,
        'fuel_2'                            => (string) $item->fuel_2,
        'mw_1'                              => (string) $item->mw_1,
        'mw_2'                              => (string) $item->mw_2,
        'mw_total'                          => (string) $item->mw_total,
        'deliverability_status'             => (string) $item->deliverability_status,
        'county'                            => (string) $item->county,
        'state'                             => (string) $item->state,
        'utility'                           => (string) $item->utility,
        'substation_or_transmission_line'   => (string) $item->substation_or_transmission_line,
        'proposed_online_date'              => $item->proposed_online_date,
        'current_online_date'               => $item->current_online_date,
        'supplemental_review'               => (string) $item->supplemental_review,
        'phase_1_cluster_study'             => (string) $item->phase_1_cluster_study,
        'phase_2_cluster_study'             => (string) $item->phase_2_cluster_study,
        'optional_study'                    => (string) $item->optional_study,
        'agreement_status'                  => (string) $item->agreement_status,
        'latitude'                          => $latitude,
        'longitude'                         => $longitude
    ]
];

$formParams = [
    'token'                 => 'aUIIAqYYo3gx-5rgBGxLGBFOn_KOm9bbNe..',
    'features'              => json_encode([$feature]),
    'f'                     => 'json',
];

$url = "https://services9.arcgis.com/Azs8YqOMYfa7g8wo/arcgis/rest/services/test_layer/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures";

// I'm using guzzle.
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post($url, ['form_params' => $formParams]);
$result = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

I'm getting success response:-

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "addResults": [
            {
                "objectId": 32,
                "uniqueId": 32,
                "globalId": null,
                "success": true
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

And data is also updated in the Feature layer data section. But that updated data points are not reflecting on the map. It seems geometry is not correct.

Comment: So you are using php to insert the feature into a feature service on ArcGIS Online? What is the spatial reference on the feature service? I believe that if a spatial reference is not included in the geometry object in the add request, then WGS84 is assumed. So if the feature service has a different spatial reference this is cause problems. https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/geometry-objects.htm

Comment: This same question was asked/answered in the GIS stackexchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327220/arcgis-feature-layer-data-update-using-api-in-php/327538#327538